# AWS Cognito Decode JWKS.json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am working on verifying the access token on AWS Cognito. One thing I have to do is to convert the key from jwks.json (of the userpool) into a rsa Public Key structure (depending on the used JWT API).

So the values for 'n' and 'e' must be big int (long) and int.

What would be the proper value of those two variables, for example:

`raw_n := "rdTmzrh7t0i_YN0MDLejnS0jXIFoSzRfFEbqf-bwGuRLnhLI4T3zGAk9HGZeAG6B5gg1D40Jsz1upo4E70VS0raGfSBPYPO7ZAJ2VCUUeblr9X_aWK4f294v4Cf3n8jZyFcGK9qhgcqy3DlHqqDANtjamWVtEhTRTFc-qoz1ScvHmPupsXlj1FsAEFEbVhP4705ez5gW3uQOoidrm38sPFwCN7g7xhA9CyzF04Zsjky55OfMCyWlIt7nljLx7ZRG3dVRD3vdEBI99qtxf43qMCWSPUk7Whn11Wf_u0xDrWhtGR9k599rKBBRWuqcujYYnFuOT0BeQIL25cePPK8lxw"
raw_e := "AQAB"`

I suppose this is Base64 URL encoded.
I am using Go and when decoding them, I am having those values:

`Value of N = 21944212446918148307583266513211511961176501179660110972882270757464120247554839864039423096862533136364974693915136668416630333929475539217929135693935014796040215031370110392351836608149288005498214604075814317642291632460369313969964278103135047317799644939426174469533574133378199425168189176269507635563270873057483981163804984573367938044175828995131343800369166239708527999544583873649523245709447765091038652758632917341001616695912404965678061555823269517387737693508193881028187912513285002546706797506255288735805912213209305939523528571103281920754204216834697552752238593850648051945624431639572960454087
Value of E = 65537`

And the final values are:

`TokenSignature= GYZQKv7o8_o9E4ktVKZngYD4BS5QluOMwE-MRcJB432CmNimQm6JbvT3H48ECThe4f3sZ1KyVbgDJbyUnlkaAwMEBjMnlV7AUaZb-ifveM7kHM30BS5LCV_SCiCk-PvmWjeIHu9bR3EwG8azJCceD5A7gDLmhAtPN94gRy-opXJPAnaCba00AwKBd_pN3UH7LYu4u4EQ29eIfn4k4RCLuR31jr7ad3dvvjhhy658dQSHzSuPZGcN1-CRVSlrd0nk0Ba2t8W33LtjxM6wzPThWgh0fpy2XEDosGU_9FiXdEjUKisE3VHxroygQ8ekVWKHssa2eujXCx8OthWzaGag0w1
Signing String= eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImpBNlFvakp0RkI0TmNIR1BmcS85ZWgzSHI2YnVXWEI0VzkxRTd5bWNjSk09In0.eyJleHAiOjE0NzAyNzgzMTEsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vY29nbml0by1pZHAudXMtZWFzdC0xLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vdXMtZWFzdC0xX0d1OFlhVGg3MiIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjRwNzNuYjhra3NsbHJrbTlzMzdzYXZsNzEzIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJtYXRlbyIsImtpZCI6IiIsImFsZyI6IiIsImp0aSI6IjhmNTBiZmU4LWVlNGUtNGFkZi04MDQxLWU5MGM4YWJkZDExZCIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MDI3NDcxMSwic3ViIjoiYjFjMDZhMTktYjE5Yy00NGMwLTgzZjctODY2NTZjYzRmMjMxIn0
rsa.PublicKey{N:21944212446918148307583266513211511961176501179660110972882270757464120247554839864039423096862533136364974693915136668416630333929475539217929135693935014796040215031370110392351836608149288005498214604075814317642291632460369313969964278103135047317799644939426174469533574133378199425168189176269507635563270873057483981163804984573367938044175828995131343800369166239708527999544583873649523245709447765091038652758632917341001616695912404965678061555823269517387737693508193881028187912513285002546706797506255288735805912213209305939523528571103281920754204216834697552752238593850648051945624431639572960454087, E:65537}`

However, with those revisiter values, I am still getting `crypto/rsa: verification error`. How can I determine if the problem is coming from the JWT Library or the values?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to verify the signature with the rsa.PublicKey generated by the program below or at https://play.golang.org/p/VZqD5m057b.  It is based on code from https://github.com/mendsley/gojwk (please see the playground link or https://github.com/mendsley/gojwk/blob/master/LICENSE for the Copyright attribution) - I would recommend to clone that repository and use it as an example and model.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    rawN := "rdTmzrh7t0i_YN0MDLejnS0jXIFoSzRfFEbqf-bwGuRLnhLI4T3zGAk9HGZeAG6B5gg1D40Jsz1upo4E70VS0raGfSBPYPO7ZAJ2VCUUeblr9X_aWK4f294v4Cf3n8jZyFcGK9qhgcqy3DlHqqDANtjamWVtEhTRTFc-qoz1ScvHmPupsXlj1FsAEFEbVhP4705ez5gW3uQOoidrm38sPFwCN7g7xhA9CyzF04Zsjky55OfMCyWlIt7nljLx7ZRG3dVRD3vdEBI99qtxf43qMCWSPUk7Whn11Wf_u0xDrWhtGR9k599rKBBRWuqcujYYnFuOT0BeQIL25cePPK8lxw"
    rawE := "AQAB"
    decodedE, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(rawE)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // make sure that the E field is at least 4 bytes, pad if necessary
    if len(decodedE) < 4 {
        ndata := make([]byte, 4)
        copy(ndata[4-len(decodedE):], decodedE)
        decodedE = ndata
    }
    pubKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
        N: &big.Int{},
        E: int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(decodedE[:])),
    }
    decodedN, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(rawN)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    pubKey.N.SetBytes(decodedN)
    fmt.Println(decodedN)
    fmt.Println(decodedE)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", *pubKey)
}
```

Output:

[173 212 230 206 184 123 183 72 191 96 221 12 12 183 163 157 45 35 92 129 104 75 52 95 20 70 234 127 230 240 26 228 75 158 18 200 225 61 243 24 9 61 28 102 94 0 110 129 230 8 53 15 141 9 179 61 110 166 142 4 239 69 82 210 182 134 125 32 79 96 243 187 100 2 118 84 37 20 121 185 107 245 127 218 88 174 31 219 222 47 224 39 247 159 200 217 200 87 6 43 218 161 129 202 178 220 57 71 170 160 192 54 216 218 153 101 109 18 20 209 76 87 62 170 140 245 73 203 199 152 251 169 177 121 99 212 91 0 16 81 27 86 19 248 239 78 94 207 152 22 222 228 14 162 39 107 155 127 44 60 92 2 55 184 59 198 16 61 11 44 197 211 134 108 142 76 185 228 231 204 11 37 165 34 222 231 150 50 241 237 148 70 221 213 81 15 123 221 16 18 61 246 171 113 127 141 234 48 37 146 61 73 59 90 25 245 213 103 255 187 76 67 173 104 109 25 31 100 231 223 107 40 16 81 90 234 156 186 54 24 156 91 142 79 64 94 64 130 246 229 199 143 60 175 37 199]
[0 1 0 1]
rsa.PublicKey{N:21944212446918148307583266513211511961176501179660110972882270757464120247554839864039423096862533136364974693915136668416630333929475539217929135693935014796040215031370110392351836608149288005498214604075814317642291632460369313969964278103135047317799644939426174469533574133378199425168189176269507635563270873057483981163804984573367938044175828995131343800369166239708527999544583873649523245709447765091038652758632917341001616695912404965678061555823269517387737693508193881028187912513285002546706797506255288735805912213209305939523528571103281920754204216834697552752238593850648051945624431639572960454087, E:65537}

Comment: Thank you! The way you do it is much cleaner, I love it.
However, I am still getting `crypto/rsa: verification error`. I suppose the conversion is correct and the problem come either from my data or from the JWT Library I am using. I should try to check with openssl
I am updating the main post with the values that we get at the end for the signing string, token signature and public key.

Comment: It is probably coming from the ParseWithClaims functions which is returning a `key invalid` but I am not sure which parameter it is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwk-to-pem) **jwk-to-pem** in my nodeJS app. As seen in the documentation:

```
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem'),
jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var jwk = { kty: 'EC', crv: 'P-256', x: '...', y: '...' },
pem = jwkToPem(jwk);

jwt.verify(token, pem);
```

You can export pem to a file and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Decoding a JWK into a `*rsa.PublicKey` can be done by unmarshing the JSON into the following data structure and using the method below.

A link to [this data structure](https://github.MicahParks/keyfunc/blob/55874f1df5a954c304e5d94c72d87032a5cbbd5b/jwks.go#L25):

```golang
// JSONKey represents a raw key inside a JWKs.
type JSONKey struct {
    Curve       string `json:"crv"`
    Exponent    string `json:"e"`
    ID          string `json:"kid"`
    Modulus     string `json:"n"`
    X           string `json:"x"`
    Y           string `json:"y"`
    precomputed interface{}
}
```

A link to [this method](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc/blob/55874f1df5a954c304e5d94c72d87032a5cbbd5b/rsa.go#L32):

```golang
// RSA parses a JSONKey and turns it into an RSA public key.
func (j *JSONKey) RSA() (publicKey *rsa.PublicKey, err error) {

    // Check if the key has already been computed.
    if j.precomputed != nil {
        var ok bool
        if publicKey, ok = j.precomputed.(*rsa.PublicKey); ok {
            return publicKey, nil
        }
    }

    // Confirm everything needed is present.
    if j.Exponent == "" || j.Modulus == "" {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: rsa", ErrMissingAssets)
    }

    // Decode the exponent from Base64.
    //
    // According to RFC 7518, this is a Base64 URL unsigned integer.
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-6.3
    var exponent []byte
    if exponent, err = base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(j.Exponent); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Decode the modulus from Base64.
    var modulus []byte
    if modulus, err = base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(j.Modulus); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create the RSA public key.
    publicKey = &rsa.PublicKey{}

    // Turn the exponent into an integer.
    //
    // According to RFC 7517, these numbers are in big-endian format.
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#appendix-A.1
    publicKey.E = int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(exponent).Uint64())

    // Turn the modulus into a *big.Int.
    publicKey.N = big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(modulus)

    // Keep the public key so it won't have to be computed every time.
    j.precomputed = publicKey

    return publicKey, nil
}
```

If you're looking to authenticate JWTs from a JWKs resource like AWS Cognito, I took these examples from a project that does just that: [`github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc`](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc)